# NodeJs API with Angular does not return JSON result

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, api, cors

**UPDATE:** I tried another API: http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Sherlock

And the GET works. However, I'm still unsure why my node.js server API does not work with this method.

---

I am currently working on the backend of an app of which I created an API similar to the tutorial: https://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/restful-api-node-and-express-4/.

However, I cannot seem to get my ionic angular app to retrieve my JSON result. When I put my get command on Postman, I get :

```
[{"floor":3}]
```

My controller is:

```
   $http({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/fl",method:'GET'})
    .then(function(response) {
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
          $log.log("success");
          $log.log("res:"+ response);
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $log.log("failed");
          $log.log("res:"+ response);
      });

 $log.log("status: "+$scope.status); 
 $log.log("data: "+$scope.data);
```

(my /fr references the JSON which has a GET method on my node server)

And always gives the result of "failed", "status: undefined" as well as "data: undefined". When I recurse this method, it gives me a "status:0".

I have also tried using $resource with no success.
Any guidance would be appreciated. My API does not have any auth and I don't think it has anything to do with CORS(unless you guys think it does).

**EDIT:**
this is the get method on my server.js:

```
//GET Floor
 router.get("/fl",function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT floor FROM stor1 WHERE id=0";

        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing MySQL query"});
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDIT2:**
Well, i added more logs to display results and now i get an [object Object] from response. The object is:
`{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:3000/api/fl","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain,*/*"}},"statusText":""}`

Comment: Have you tried `$log.log(response)`? To check what the response holds.

Comment: what is your response

Comment: `[{"floor":3}]` this is wrong way for accesing data

Comment: $log.log(response) = undefined.
Well Wasiq, I just wanted to get the JSON from the "GET" method.

Comment: can you put ```$log.log(response)``` instead of the line ```$log.log("success")``` and ```$log.log("failed");``` in your controller ?

Comment: You shouldn't expect the values to be set outside of the `.then()` callbacks (asynchronous).

Comment: I kept the success and failure so I could tell which function was running. Also, Im recursively calling the methods every 5 seconds and after the initial run, JSON given shows that the `data: null` and the `status:0`. I was hoping the `$scope.data` and `$scope.status` would stay otherwise would I put the results in a cache of sorts?.

Comment: it has everything to do with CORS, while hitting API from angular APP you have to implement CORS in the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postman seems to get the response for the `GET` request which means your server side code is fine with routing. But your Angular App is unable to get any response with out throwing any error in the server side. Which seems to be the case of **CORS**

```
var cors = require('cors');    
app.use(cors());
```

**Note**: Use this middleware before your first route.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I've been stuck on this for a whole day! When all I needed to do was a npm install on my server.js. I'm so happy right now. Gonna go talk a little walk around the compound.

Comment: this thing comes once in every once's life. Reason being that your node.js server is located separately than your client server which is hosting your angularJS App. Thus your browser does not let you to access the contents of different domain. Thus we add a header ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` via cors middleware.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to make ***Access-Control-Allow-Origin***

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but how would you add that to the "GET" methods?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding names for the success and error callback functions, like so:

```
$http({url:"http://localhost:3000/api/fl",method:'GET'})
.then(function successCallBack(response) { // Add 'successCallBack' function name
      $scope.status = response.status;
      $scope.data = response.data;
      $log.log("success");
      $log.log("res:"+ response);
    }, function errorCallBack(response) { // Add 'errorCallBack' function name
      $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
      $scope.status = response.status;
      $log.log("failed");
      $log.log("res:"+ response);
  });

$log.log("status: "+$scope.status); 
$log.log("data: "+$scope.data);
```

Comment: Doesn't really change the result. My locally hosted API still refuses to give.

Comment: adding name won't change anything, as javascript points to the reference of the first argument as successCallBack and second argument as errorCallBack irrespective of the names.